# Inject to NPSWF32.dll & Flash10a.ocx & flashplayer.xpt to create a global ActionScript VM console and debugger?

Tags: flash, debugging, dll, actionscript, hook

since all browser's Flash plugin is based on:
NPSWF32.dll
Flash10a.ocx
flashplayer.xpt

Is there a way to inject these dll's, use some voodoo to create a global ActionScript VM console and debugger?

Perhaps then I can submit arbitary score to any online Flash games?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would be hard to do what you are saying - an easier way to submit an arbitrary score to online Flash games would be to:

Get the swf, decompile it, work out how it works and then you could potentially hijack your own session and submit whatever data you want.

You could also monitor what the swf sends back to the host and potentially emulate/edit that. Its most likely going to be some simple POST variables.